# Max number of elements which sum is less than equal target in unsorted array (without sorting)

Tags: algorithm, selection

I am working on an algorithm question which is as follows:

An array of (elements) real numbers in arbitrary unsorted order, find the maximum number of elements whose sum is less than equal to Target value in O(n) time. Therefore no sorting is allowed.

I think I should use Randomized QuickSelect algorithm which find the Kth element in unsorted array in O(n). I want to know what is the right modification in Randomized QuickSelect algorithm in order to use for my question?

Comment: Are you sure it's possible with `O(n)` at all? Where did you find the question?

Comment: As far as I know it may not be possible to do it in O(n)

Answer (score 0):

In Randomized QuickSelect algorithm, array is partitioned against a randomized position value. Lower part partition contains all the values less than this randomized position value and upper partition contains all the value greater than this randomized position value. For your problem, you will calculate the sum of this lower partition array. Now if the sum is less than the target value, then choose a random position value from the upper partition and run the partition algorithm again. If the sum is greater than the target value, choose a random position value from the lower partition and run the partition algorithm again. Continue it until you find the answer. Note, in worst case this could be O(n^2).